# Parse information into listView

Tags: android, parsing, android-listview

i am asking you for help. As you see from the picture it is a result that i should have, but, at the moment i have information orinted on my left corner. what i am doing wrog?

[image]

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

    /** Items entered by the user is stored in this ArrayList variable */
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();


    /** Declaring an ArrayAdapter to set items to ListView */
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

    TextView mTvSDate;
    TextView mTvSName;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        OnClickListener listener = new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent("com.example.SecondElementActivity");
                startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
            }
        };

        ImageButton addBtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.addBtn);
        addBtn.setOnClickListener(listener);   
        Log.d("Suceess1","Sucess1");

    }
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        // Defining the ArrayAdapter to set items to ListView 
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);

       // Getting reference to TextView tv_sage of the layout file activity_student
      //  mTvSDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editDate);

       // Getting reference to TextView tv_sname of the layout file activity_student
         mTvSName = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.editName);
         Log.d("Suceess5","Sucess5");

        // Fetching data from a parcelable object passed from MainActivity
        NoteElement drug = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("drug");
      //  MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(this, generateData());
        Log.d("Suceess6","Sucess6");


        list.add(mTvSName.getText().toString());
        mTvSName.setText(drug.mSName);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

**SecondElementActivity.java**

```
    public class SecondElementActivity extends Activity{

    EditText mEtSDate;
    EditText mEtSName;
    Button btnSave;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second_element);

        // Getting a reference to EditText et_sname of the layout activity_main
        mEtSName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editName);

        // Getting a reference to EditText et_sage of the layout activity_main
        mEtSDate = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editDate);

        // Getting a reference to Button btn_ok of the layout activity_main
        btnSave = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSave);

        // Setting onClick event listener for the "OK" button
        btnSave.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                // Creating an instance of NoteElement class with user input data
                NoteElement drug = new NoteElement(
                        mEtSDate.getText().toString(),
                        mEtSName.getText().toString());

                // Creating an intent to open the activity MainActivity
                Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MainActivity.class);

                // Passing data as a parecelable object to MainActivity
                intent.putExtra("drug",drug);

                // Opening the activity
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Parcelable class **NoteElement.java**

```
  public class NoteElement implements Parcelable{

    String mSDate;
    String mSName;

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    /**
    * Storing the NoteElement data to Parcel object
    **/
    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(mSDate);
        dest.writeString(mSName);

    }

    /**
    * A constructor that initializes the NoteElement object
    **/
    public NoteElement(String sDate, String sName){
        this.mSDate = sDate;
        this.mSName = sName;
    }

    /**
    * Retrieving NoteElement data from Parcel object
    * This constructor is invoked by the method createFromParcel(Parcel source) of
    * the object CREATOR
    **/
    private NoteElement(Parcel in){
        this.mSDate = in.readString();
        this.mSName = in.readString();

    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<NoteElement> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<NoteElement>() {

        @Override
        public NoteElement createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
            return new NoteElement(source);
        }

        @Override
        public NoteElement[] newArray(int size) {
            return new NoteElement[size];
        }
    };
}
```

And my activity_main have such a .xml file

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/addBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_new"         
        android:contentDescription="@string/desc"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/addBtn"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="53dp"
        android:text="@string/mainTxt"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textSize="32sp" />


   <!-- Student version --> 
       <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_sname"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textIsSelectable="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_sdate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textIsSelectable="true" />

    <!-- List -->
    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/addBtn" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

**activity_second.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >



  <ImageButton
      android:id="@+id/addBtn"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
      android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
      android:src="@drawable/ic_action_new"
      android:contentDescription="@string/desc"/>

  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/textView1"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/addBtn"
      android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
      android:layout_marginLeft="53dp"
      android:text="@string/mainTxt"
      android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
      android:textSize="32sp" />

 <!-- Date -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/date"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginRight="36dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/editDate"
        android:text="@string/date" />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editDate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/editName"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="date"
        android:hint="@string/str_hnt_date" />

  <!-- Name -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editName"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/date"
        android:text="@string/name" />
     <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/date"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/str_hnt_name" />

 <!-- Dosage -->
     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dosage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/editText3"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText3"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/notes"
        android:text="@string/dosage" />
     <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editName"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editName"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/str_hnt_dosage"  />

  <!-- Notes -->
      <TextView
        android:id="@+id/notes"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/editText4"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText4"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/name"
        android:text="@string/notes" />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText3"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText3"
        android:ems="10" 
        android:hint="@string/str_hnt_notes"/>


<!-- buttons: Save and Selete-->
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSave"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText4"
        android:layout_below="@+id/notes"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="@string/btnSave" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btnSave"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/addBtn"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btnSave"
        android:text="@string/btnDelete" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so you have two activities total right?

Here's the deal: Look at your image. Activity 1 starts activity 2 right? And you're expecting to get information from your activity 2 back to activity 1, correct? Alright.

First thing to learn:

```
startActivity(intent);
```

This method states that you will just initiate an activity but expect nothing back from it. So even if you want to send information back to activity 1 THROUGH activitiy 2 it will not work. Instead you must do this:

```
startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

The second parameter is an integer that can help you differentiate between different activity calls, it is not important for you right now.

Now, because you say "ForResult" in your method above, in your MainActivity now you must implement this:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    // here  you will work with the code.
    // data is your intent data sent from activity 2
    // where you say this in your own code:

    // Passing data as a parecelable object to MainActivity
    // intent.putExtra("drug",drug);

}
```

Now the last thing to note:

In SecondElementActivity.java where you have this:

```
// Opening the activity
   startActivity(intent);
```

It is wrong. You know why? because you're saying that you want to start a new activity. But in Android you already have a parent for this activity, which is activity 1. So your activity 1 called 2, when you end activity 2 it will go back to 1. So, replace that line for this:

```
setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
finish();
```

EDIT:

Also I don't know if this is correct, I don't do it this way, so here is my fix:

```
OnClickListener listener = new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent("com.example.SecondElementActivity");
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    };
```

When you say you want to make a new intent you should pass two parameters:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondElementActivity.class);
```

The second parameter is the name of the class you want to call.

Comment: Everything is correct. i think i understand you, but is my xml good? cause there is something that i don't like from <!-- Student version --> to List – 

What id i should put into this line:
        mTvSName = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.?????????????);
I think that it shoud be from activity_second_element.xml this:
 android:id="@+id/editName"
but this is but this is EditText field, not a ViewText field, how to solve that?

Comment: @user2956929 : it is incorrect from my pov coz `tv_sname` nd `tv_sdate` will overlap with each other.

Comment: i modiefied files by your solution, but now i am gettig NullPointerException in Main file at 71 line:  list.add(mTvSName.getText().toString()); so what is wrong now? In here udated only MainActivity file.

Comment: One suggestion: mTvSName = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.editName); initiate your mTvSName on the protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) method. Right after the setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this :

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/addBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"         
        android:contentDescription="@string/hello_world"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/addBtn"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="mainTxt"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textSize="32sp" />

    <!-- List -->
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/myListView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Follow [**This tutorial**](http://hmkcode.com/android-custom-listview-items-row/) for populating `ListView` just change `adapter` and `row.xml` from that tutorial

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_sdate "
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:textSize="12sp" >
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_sname"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tv_sdate "
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:textSize="12sp" >
    </TextView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

- http://hmkcode.com/android-custom-listview-items-row/